# How to create a blinking light with a push button in PLC?

Tags: button, plc, light, delta, ladder-logic

I have create a ladder diagram to control the light with a push button. I want make a blinking light with my push button. I have create a ladder diagram to control them. When I press the button, the light will start to blink. However, when I release my hand from the button, the light will turn off. I want to make it keep blinking when I press the button.

[In the image, it is the ladder diagram that I created. M0 is the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SvTI.png)

Comment: While you hold the button, your logic is basically `if M0 and not M2 then Y0` but once you let go it becomes `if Y0 and not M2 then Y0`. `M2` will eventually be true, making `Y0` false.

Answer (score 2):

As you did not specify exactly the model of the PLC and the program (IDE), I created this example for a Delta DVP programmed in the ISPSoft software (v3.14), it is similar to yours, except for the memory for the times, here I left the time fixed at 1 second for each timer.

- Y0 will flash when pressing (OFF > ON) the M0 button.
- Here I use a rising edge detection for M0, this is optional for your case.
- I put M1 to stop the program (instead of M2) and put M2 as a memory to hold the state.

[image: Program example]